# Drop Down and File menu in TKinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to read file and display it and get user input like in how many minutes he want that file to be displayed.
Currently I'm using `.get()` to input file path and minutes after which he want that file to be displayed but to make it more user readable I want to implement drop down menu showing minutes and file box (D:/ drive view of particular folder where file resides).

How can I code it using python Tkinter ?

I researched but no luck as of now.

----EDIT----

Snippet of how I'm doing it manually

```
def add_item():
 print(link_text.get(),small_break.get(),large_break.get(),maxrun_hours.get(),maxrun_minutes.get()
    ,exerun_hours.get(),exerun_minutes.get())

if link_text.get() == '' or small_break.get() == '' or large_break.get() == '' or maxrun_hours.get() == '' or maxrun_minutes.get() == '' or exerun_hours.get() == '' or exerun_minutes.get() == '':
messagebox.showerror('Required Fields', 'Please include all fields')
return
```

How I take input:

```
link_text = StringVar()
link_label = Label(app, text='TT-LINK', font=('bold', 14), pady=20, foreground="white",bg="black")
link_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
link_entry = Entry(app, textvariable=link_text, relief="solid")
link_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated !

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and also provide us a minimal working example. Show us some code. You have to help us to help you.

Comment: @buhtz I hope edit helps you in order to help moi !

Comment: It is a good first step but you have to do more. Please read carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Use correct indention. Break your lines at round about 80 chars to prevent your (free time investing) readers from horizontal scrolling. And use correct PEP8 coding style. Your code is very hard to read and doesn't run out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
example = StringVar()
example_label = Label(app, text='example')
example_label.grid(add positional cords)
list = ttk.Combobox(app, textvariable=example)
# Adding combobox drop down list
list['values'] = ('Enter entries manually to populate')
list.grid(add positional cords)
list.current()
```

Hope that helps...!